# Installing NVIDIA drivers appears to be inconsistent

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, package-management, graphics

Following the instructions [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu), I am attempting to install some specific NVIDIA drivers on Ubuntu 18.04. I am doing this as the first thing after a fresh installation of Ubuntu, such that there are no NVIDIA drivers already installed.

The instructions say to run:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends nvidia-driver-418
```

After doing this, I run `apt list --installed | grep nvidia` to see what NVIDIA packages it has installed. It prints out 17 package names, including `nvidia-driver-418` and `nvidia-driver-430`.

Then, I run `nvidia-smi`, and this print out `Driver Version: 430.26`.

I have also looked at `Ubuntu Software -> Additional Drivers`, and the checked radio button is for `Using NVIDIA metapackage from nvidia-driver-430` (proprietary, tested). Below this is an unchecked radio button for `Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-410 (open source)`.

This doesn't seem very consistent to me... My questions are:

1. Why does installing `nvidia-driver-418` actually install both `nvidia-driver-418` and `nvidia-driver-430`?
2. Given that `430.26` is the driver being used by my system (presumably from the `nvidia-driver-430` package), how can I tell my system to actually use the `418` version of the driver? It seems that I could use `Ubuntu Software -> Additional Drivers`, but this lists version 410, not version 418. And I haven't even installed version 410... What's going on?

Comment: There is no 418 driver in Ubuntu 18.04 repos. The 418 meta package was left for compatibility. What is so good with the 418?

Comment: I'm not saying there is anything so good about it, I'm just trying to understand how this all works... I don't understand why installing one package actually installs another package.

Comment: Simply because `nvidia-driver-418` is actually a link to 430.